# Output content from custom wordpress editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using an options framework  (NHP Theme Options) for my wordpress theme, I don't have a problem with things like adding things like 'if' statements, ex if option is selected 'echo' this information.

That alone allows for a lot of dynamic options. I added a wordpress editor box in my admin panel and I am a little lost on how I would output the information that is inside the box.

It's inside my theme options page inside an array,

```
    array(
                    'id' => 'header-area',
                    'type' => 'editor',
                    'title' => __('Editor Option', 'my-opts'), 
                    'sub_desc' => __('Can also use the validation methods if required', 'my-opts'),
                    'desc' => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'my-opts'),
                    'std' => 'headarea'
),
```

typically I use if statements, here is an example of how I output my options.

```
    <?php if( my_opts_get('header-area') ) { 

      $fixed_header_css = 'top: 0;';

  } else {

      $fixed_header_css = 'top: 51px;';

} ?>
```

This is just an example, but I am a PHP novice and don't know how to output the editor array.

I know its not by using an if statement, I tried things like

```
    <?php echo my_opts_get('header-area') ?>
```

I think that may be close, but I am obviously missing something

Comment: Which of the items inside that array are you trying to modify? What would you like it to be instead?

Comment: Not trying to modify but output the data inputted inside the box.

it connects to field_editor.php which has a function function render()

Comment: Inside the function handles all the data, I don't know the proper syntax to output the content..

The array basically creates the box inside the wordpress backend for me, but when data is entered into the box, I am just seeking the syntax to output it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right under my nose, using this simple line of code was all I needed to output the data..

```
    <?php echo moon_opts_get('header-present-area', 'home-area'); ?>
```